# How can I troubleshoot an iptables rule that is preventing internet access from my server?

Tags: ubuntu, iptables, web-server

So I am facing a strange issue, not able to make any sense. Hope someone here can help me understand. I have my iptable rules set like this

```
root@COV0495:~# iptables -S
-P INPUT DROP
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-N ufw-after-forward
-N ufw-after-input
-N ufw-after-logging-forward
-N ufw-after-logging-input
-N ufw-after-logging-output
-N ufw-after-output
-N ufw-before-forward
-N ufw-before-input
-N ufw-before-logging-forward
-N ufw-before-logging-input
-N ufw-before-logging-output
-N ufw-before-output
-N ufw-reject-forward
-N ufw-reject-input
-N ufw-reject-output
-N ufw-track-forward
-N ufw-track-input
-N ufw-track-output
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.*.*.*/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 192.*.*.*/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j LOG
-A FORWARD -j LOG
```

While I can access the sites hosted on the server over internet, I can't access anything on the internet from within the server. Here is a sample ping request output:

```
root@COV0495:~# ping bing.com
ping: bing.com: Temporary failure in name resolution`
```

Now I have noticed that If i change the first rule to `-P INPUT ACCEPT` then I am able to access resources on the internet from within the server again.

What I am confused about though is why does the `-P INPUT DROP` affect traffic going out of the server?

I have tried enabling DNS inbound requests with rules like this

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

But it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default DROP policy in your ruleset affects the *replies*: your query was done, a reply was sent back from remote to your server, and then your server dropped this reply. Final result: no reply meaning no connectivity.

Your last attempt with:

> ```
> -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 53 -m state --state ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
> ```

should have made the DNS part work. Leading to the next step: an attempt to connect to the resource now it was resolved. But then again this attempt failed for the same reason: replies are dropped.

You're missing a *generic* stateful rule, which should be the very first rule in the ruleset:

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

It will allow replies to any query sent by the hosts itself, including related errors (typically reeived as ICMP) because such query is memorized by Netfilter's *conntrack* facility for stateful operations (and also for NAT when relevant).

Should a REJECT rule be added later, then above [should be followed by](https://git.netfilter.org/iptables/commit/?id=63291783a1a264b0d44606442f38435a5ac362c6):

```
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

(that's not needed here).

To have this take effect immediately, just run as root, using `-I` instead of `-A`:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

---

Note that Docker's containers are unaffected, because everything going to or from Docker's containers is routed (because of NAT), so traverses filter/FORWARD instead of filter/INPUT. They might still have been affected when relying on host's services, possibly DNS resolution.